# How to hide a foreign key field and populate it in a view in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to post two forms to one view method where one of the forms contains a field which is a foreign key to the model of the other form.

I can hide the foreign key field from the form, but when I try to save the second form

```
formData = ThisForm(request.POST)
formData.save()
```

I get the following error message

```
field_id may not be NULL
```

Even if I try assign the field before saving

```
name = firstForm.cleaned_data['field']
formData.creator = name
```

Anyone got an idea on the correct way to acheive this?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
With help from the answer below, this is what worked in the end

```
f1 = Form1(request.POST)
f1.save()
x = f1.cleaned_data

f2 = Form2(request.POST)
y = f2.save(commit=False)
n = FirstClass.objects.get(the_field= x["the_field"])
y.the_field = n
y.save()
```

Comment: Hah I did the exact same thing - you want to save the session user or whatever into the field? I even called it creator as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obj = formData.save(commit=False)
obj.creator = whatever
obj.save()
```